# How do you say "to bail somebody out of jail" in German?

Tags: idiom

My friend is in jail for burglary and to get him out, you have to pay 5,000 dollars. How do you say `to bail someone out` in German? Can I say `Jmdn aus dem Gefängnis herausbringen` or does it have to be idiomatic ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's

> jdn. aus dem Gefängnis holen

Comment: I am not sure this is a good suggestion - it includes *any way* of freeing the person, e.g. with force, by blasting a hole into the prison, or by bribing some official ...

Answer (score 17):

The whole concept is a little bit different over here. If somebody is taken into pre-trial custody, there's usually a good reason for that. Sometimes a "Haftverschonung gegen Auflagen" is possible, but you're deep into lawyers' turf here.

"Put up bail, get out of jail" (for now) is nowhere near as automatic as in the US, where sometimes only the amount seems to be in question.

That said, "(die) Kaution stellen" would be an idiomatic expression.

Comment: There are (ASFAIK, I'm no lawyer) exactly three reasons one might be kept in pre-trial custody: 1. There's risk of fleeing, 2. The suspect could be performing another crime, 3. The suspect might try to wipe evidence. All of course in the view of a "Staatsanwalt" (~ county attorney). Hardly anthing of this can be prevented by money.

Comment: Well, the flight risk could be greatly reduced by some additional measures (surrender your passport, perhaps report at the local precinct regularly, etc.), especially if you're "fully integrated", i.e. have a job, a family and a place to live. 

This is not true, granted, if you are held for fear of re-offending or suppression of evidence.

Comment: I agree. That's why some citizen of the local town (with maybe even a familly there) is less likely to be kept in custody for reason #1.

Comment: Bail ("Sicherheitsleistung") is possible if "Fluchtgefahr" is the main reason for pre-trial custody ("Untersuchungshaft, short: U-Haft). It is laid down in §11a STtPO: http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/stpo/__116a.html

Comment: Ob die Praxis üblich ist oder nicht, hierzulande, bedeutet nicht, dass man nicht in Muttersprache über die Vorgänge, wie sie etwa in den USA sind, reden könnte. Eine Unzahl an synchronisierten Filmen aus den USA beweist es. :)